# Is Initialization Vector should be hidden?

Tags: c#, aes

I'm creating some encryption logic for saving files, and going to apply AES Encryption.

Actually, I have been implemented AES Encryption at Online Encrypter, not creating encryption logic myself, So I couldn't realized the existence of IV.

Struggling, however, I found the function `RijndaelManaged.GenerateIV()`.

I think auto-generated IV should be stored in somewhere of destination file, to decrypt file successfully, but It should be hidden like encryption key.

Is it okay to just append 'plain' IV to behind of file? If it isn't, how can I store, and use IV more properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I derive the key and initialization vector for my AES encrypted database entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193140/how-should-i-derive-the-key-and-initialization-vector-for-my-aes-encrypted-datab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initialization vector` (IV) should be **unique** and **random** for each plaintext that is encrypted with a key. However, it does **not need to be secret**. You can prepend the IV to the cipher text and transmit it in cleartext.

The reason for an IV is to ensure that the encryption of the first block is unique. For example, if you encrypted the same message with the same key using `AES/CBC` and did not provide an IV, the output would be identical. Introducing an IV means that the first block (16 bytes) of the cipher text will be unique, and thus, the entire message cipher text will be different (due to the CBC mode of operation). See Wikipedia's article on [Block Cipher Modes of Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for more details.